# Indicator applet and sound manager for OSS sound system

Tags: sound, applet, oss-sound-system

Alsa wasn't functioning well on my laptop. The open source OSS sound system also failed to install. So I installed the closed source version of OSS and it is working fine. But the volume indicator applet in the system tray disappeared after installing OSS. The sound manager in `System -> Preferences` is giving an error. I tried to do `sudo apt-get install oss4-gtk` but it also tries to install `oss4-base'(which is open source version). How can I install the volume indicator applet and sound manager for closed source version of OSS?

Comment: There's a closed source version of OSS? Can you be more specific as to which version you've installed?

Comment: Yes. That's what I am using.

Comment: There is indeed, who knew!

Comment: In my humble opinion, you should have try to find a way to make ALSA work. Installing the "closed source version of OSS" I don't call that a solution but more problems to come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backend is tied to a pulse sink, so you need to load the oss module in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` instead of using udev-detect.